# where to put the code working on input file (Shiny, R)

Tags: r, input, shiny

I have difficulties putting some code into a separate file.

The following code works:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(

            fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                      accept=c('text/csv', 
                               'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                               '.csv')),

            tags$hr()

        ),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput('contents')
        )
    )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    getData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        data = read.csv(inFile$datapath)
        ### CleanData
        data = data %>%
            mutate_each(funs(toupper)) %>%    
            mutate_each(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", .))) %>%
            mutate_each(funs(str_trim)) %>%
            mutate_each(funs(rm_white)) %>%
            sample_frac(1) 

    })

    output$contents = renderTable({
        getData()

    })

})
```

---

But if I put some code into a separate file, it doesn't work.

ui.R doesn't change

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    getData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        data = read.csv(inFile$datapath)
        ### CleanData
        source('CleanData.R')

    })

    output$contents = renderTable({
        getData()

    })

})
```

CleanData.R (in the same directory in laptop)

```
data = data %>%
    mutate_each(funs(toupper)) %>%    
    mutate_each(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", .))) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(str_trim)) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(rm_white)) %>%
    sample_frac(1)
```

It doesn't work, giving an error

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Somebody know how to fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, compound questions are usually discouraged. It might make sense to separate your problems out into individual questions.

Comment: Is there a function within `CleanData.R`? Try calling `source('CleanData.R')` outside the `reactive` expression, just after the `shinyServer(function(input, output))` line. Then, within your `getData()` call the function name that's in CleanData

Comment: Thanks @tospig  `CleanData.R` just has lines of code (not a function). Do i have to write it as a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because when you `source` the CleanData.R, it is evaluated in the global environment where `data` hasn't been defined by you, so it is referring to the function `data`.  You can add `local=TRUE` to the `source` call to have it evaluated in the calling environment,

```
    source('CleanData.R', local=TRUE)
```